# mailto in html forms is failing to send mail

Tags: html

```html
<form action="mailto:tejascs289022@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
  <div>
    <label for="text">Name</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="name: " placeholder="First Name">
    <input type="text" name="name: " placeholder="Last Name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email:" placeholder="emample@gmail.com">
    <div>
      <label for="floatingTextarea2">Comments</label>
      <textarea placeholder="Leave a comment here" id="floatingTextarea2" style="height: 100px"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
  </div>
</form>
```

I am writing to you regarding an issue I am currently facing with the mailto attribute. I have been trying to use this attribute in my HTML code to create a clickable email link, but it doesn't seem to be working properly.

When I click on the link, it opens up a new email message in my default email client, but the recipient email address and subject line are not being pre-filled as they should be. I have checked my code multiple times and can't seem to find any errors.

I was wondering if you have any suggestions on how I can fix this issue? I would greatly appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: You have no `subject` parameter neither in action URI nor as a named input; where do you expect it should come from?

Comment: can you explain please.

Comment: You should probably have something like `<form action="mailto:...@...?subject=SOMETHING"` that would work with POST method. Or named input and send it through GET.